# Failed to load font-family downloaded from google fonts in create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, node-sass, google-fonts

I have downloaded google fonts in my create-react-app project.

In package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

In App.scss

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Tangerine";
    src: local("Tangerine"), url("/src/assets/fonts/Tangerine/Tangerine-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    src: local("Roboto"), url("/src/assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

$font-home-page: "Tangerine", "Roboto";
```

Error message produced when I run my app

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/App.scss)
Error: Can't resolve './src/assets/fonts/Tangerine/Tangerine-Regular.ttf' in '/Users/.../src'
```

Do you know what's the issue I run into?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by correcting the static assets path in App.scss.

Now the App.scss file looks like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Tangerine";
    src: local("Tangerine"), url("../src/assets/fonts/Tangerine/Tangerine-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    src: local("Roboto"), url("../src/assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

$font-home-page: "Tangerine",
"Roboto";
```

Just simply put '..' before the paths in url().

For more information on how create-react-app load fonts and images
[create-react-app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)